# Unity3D Only render when key is pressed

Tags: c#, unity, rendering, latency

I am researching Interaction Latency - the delay between pressing a key and seeing the result on screen.

I have my Unity3D application deployed remotely to an EC2 instance on AWS. I have another application, on the client, sending keyboard and mouse events to the server Unity3D application.

My goal is to measure the time between pressing a key or moving the mouse on the client and having the corresponding image displayed (on the client!). A GUID is sent from the client to the server and when the image comes back, it has the GUID that supposedly matches the command which generated the command which calls `ReadPixels` (yes, I know `RenderTarget` is faster, but I do not have the Pro license, yet).

My system works well, but I am concerned that the frame that the client receives (and which I measure against), is not the result of key that was pressed. The reason for this is because Unity3D renders, regardless of whether or not it received a command from the client application.

I'd like to only render if a key press is received from the client.

How can I do this? Any suggestions on how to measure the delay between the client key press and the updated image on the client is also welcome.

Comment: "yes, I know RenderTargetis faster, but I do not have the Pro license, yet". FYI: I think RenderTextures are now available in the free versions of Unity too.

Comment: Would simply disabling/reenabling the camera be a suitable option?